# Display an image without saving it

Tags: android

My app can download an image from a raspberry. it works fine. This is the code

```
public void downloadFile() {

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect("******");
            ftpClient.login("****","*****");
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);


            String remoteFile1;

            File downloadFile1 = new File(filePath);


            OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
            boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
            outputStream1.close();

            if (success) {
                System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error in downloading file !");
            }

            boolean logout = ftpClient.logout();
            if (logout) {
                System.out.println("Connection close...");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I can display it so the user of my app can see it. For the image loading, Im using this code and it works too.

```
private void loadImage(String imagePath) {
        Uri imageUri;
        String fullImagePath;
        Drawable image;
        ImageView imageDisplay;

        imageUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
        fullImagePath = imageUri.getPath();
        image = Drawable.createFromPath(fullImagePath);

        imageDisplay=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);

        imageDisplay.setImageDrawable(image);
    }
```

Now I want to display the image without downloading it in my gallery. But I can't figure out how to do this. 
Can someone help me please.

Comment: *I want to display the image(remote) without downloading* not possible

Comment: why not? You are free to save this image or not

Comment: downloading != saving ... yes, you can store image in memory(which will cause sooner or later memory issues) without saving but still you have to download it ...

Comment: Im sorry my english is not that good, I will edit my question, im talking about saving the image

Comment: you need somthing like [_this_](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/175966ef024b4052c195fa7db34bdec4) but in second thread instead using URLConnection code just use your code for downloading from FTP just write to `pipedOutputStream` instead your `outputStream1`

Comment: @Selvin, I think you have a great idea but I dont get it. Im trying to do what you are suggesting but I dont understand the idea.

Comment: *but I dont understand the idea* sorry, then i'm unable to help you ...

Comment: I found an idea, after downloading the image, display it, then file.delete

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show an image without download it. Actually when you see something "remotely", you are downloading it.

If you mean that the image is too large and you don't want to download, but want a mechanism for the user can view it. One possible solution is make a thumbnail (reduced image) in server side and show that "preview" to the user. Then if the user want to download it to the gallery you could get the original image.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display an image without downloading it, it has to be uploaded in a image hosting site or alike so you will just use the link instead of the whole FTP Client.

Basically, you are using a code that is intended for saving an image. And the one you are using for loading the images fetches data from the Drawable. So you are in the wrong path.

Comment: *so you will just use the link* ... well, "link" is a magical thing so if you would use "link" the data will spawn on device from remote server without downloading (oh wait, "link" can also looks like `ftp://server/file_path/file`) ... *you are using a code that is intended for saving an image* ... that's why he can not pipe outputstream to inputstream and feed Bitmap.decodeStream with it without saving